# How to set the size attribute of a select field?

Tags: 7, forms

When you use a "select" field with multiple values Drupal generates this HTML:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="..." id="..." class="...">
```

How can I inject the size="..." attribute? This will cause the box to show more values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to do it with the [`#size` property of the Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#size). I am not sure, but you might need to also set the [`#multiple`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#multiple) property to `TRUE` in order for the `#size` to be honored.

It it also not clear from the question if you are creating your own form using the Form API, modifying an existing Form API form using a [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), or writing your own form HTML (which I imagine - and hope - you are not doing).

Comment: thanks. I'm trying to modify a term reference field in the "node add/edit" form. I'm added  $form['field_disc_topic']['#size'] = 20; with a hook_form_alter and the attribute shows up in the dpm but has no effect on the form field. I wonder if it's because the type says "container"?   http://awesomescreenshot.com/095rpiq86

Comment: I figured it out,  $form['field_disc_topic']['und']['#size'] = 20; did the trick. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Try this to modify Select list Height & width drupal Way

```
// Increase Height of Select list
$form['field_example1']['und']['#size'] = 15;

// Increase Height of Select list
$form['field_example2']['#size'] = 20;
```

Comment: This does not modify the width. Only the height of the dropdown box is adjusted.